# Has anyone unlocked Grand Moff Tarkin or Overbridge?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've spent hundreds of bux unlocking just some of the salvage droid items, and I get that there is a pretty consistent theme - Chiss stuff from Csilla, Ewoks from Endor, Wookies from Kashyyk, Droids from the Shipwreck.  But I haven't seen anything that would unlock Grand Moff Tarkin or the new imperial level Overbridge.  Has anyone managed to unlock these yet, or seen something that might hint that they are unlocked some other way?

Comment: Have you actually gotten all 6 other levels? I have got 5 and am struggling to get Chiss Hsp.

Comment: I've spent 700 Bux so far and haven't gotten any levels, only coins and imperial stuff I already have

Comment: My spouse has Wilhuff Tarkin giving massages in the Cloud City Spa... but that's probably not what you are asking.

Comment: @Natalia, how much bux have u spent to get those 5 levels? I've spent about 700+ bux and gotten the 2 Endor levels.

Comment: I wasn't really counting the Bux I spent on the event but give or take, around 1k to get all levels and a couple of characters. I believe this is all random and based on luck. Also, I think only the Gold Salvage Droid (25 Bux) is capable of fetching you levels whole the Silver (15 Bux) is good enough for characters. That's my observation thus far. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Both are now available as rewards for the Imperial Propaganda decoration event which started on the 20th March and finishes on the 30th.

I think Tarkin was 30 or 35 decorated levels and Overbridge was 60.

I've spent 300 bux on decoration droids to get Tarkin and Overbridge.
I *was* saving up for the inifi-lift elevator... Oh well, back to saving. :)

Answer (score 0):

No. All indications are that they aren't available yet.